# Specifying Conditional Trace Listener in Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

I want to make calls like the following in my code:

`System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Starting XYZ...");`

and write it to a file as described in the config:

`<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="TextWriter"
             initializeData="trace.log" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>`

This works great, apart from the fact there are existing calls to `WriteLine()` that are currently getting mixed up with the new lines of code I've added.

How can I write my trace to one log file and leave the existing ones as they are (currently no config at all before I amended it, I'd like the existing trace to be handled as it currently is).

I know this is achievable through code, but I'd like to specify the file in the config file and conditionally write to it.

Answer (score 2):

Just understood what your question was asking. Edited my comment. You can use trace sources like in the following: http://olondono.blogspot.com/2008/01/about-trace-listeners.html

Basically you can modify your config file like this:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true"/>
          <sources>
            <source name="myTraceSource"
              switchName="mySwitch"
              switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" >
           <listeners>
            <clear/>
            <add name="textwriterListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\myLog.txt" />
           </listeners>
         </source>
     </sources>
     <switches>
       <add name="mySwitch" value="Warning" />
     </switches>
   </system.diagnostics>
```

Then in your code you can do the following:

```
    // First step: create the trace source object
    TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("myTraceSource");

    // Writing out some events
    ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 0, "warning message");
    ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, "error message");
    ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "information message");
    ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Critical, 0, "critical message");
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `TraceSource` this allows your app to write to traceForStartUp, traceForPerfomance, joesTrace, legacyTraceThatIDontWantToCommentout and then turn them on or off depending on what sort of trace you're interested in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can further filter a trace source, (i.e. send trace to the log from 9-5, but have a different trace listener send trace to an email listener after hours)  But I don't think that is what you are looking for, it just happens to be the name of a class in this namespace.